# Can't locate object method "attrs" via package "Mojo::DOM"

Tags: macos, perl, google-voice

I'm having issues with using the Google Voice API to send a text message.  I'm running Mac OS X Maveriks and it was working on the previous version (Mountain Lion).  I got the Google Voice API installed but now I get this strange message.

`Can't locate object method "attrs" via package "Mojo::DOM" at /Library/Perl/5.16/Google/Voice.pm line 39.`

I am not sure what to do with this.  I used CPAN to install Google::Voice which seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by https://github.com/tempire/perl-google-voice, I think you are missing the Mojolicious prerequisite. I don't know how Perl is set up on your machine, so I will just point out that http://mojolicio.us/ provides installation instructions.

Comment: Thank you, I was, and now it is fixed by obtaining that.  Took me a while but, I appriciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a pretty easy fix. There are two lines in the Google::Voice.pm where you need to change the method 'attrs' to 'attr'

as in

```
 $self->rnr_se($el->attrs->{value});
```

to .

```
 $self->rnr_se($el->attr->{value});
```

Change and save and you should be good to go.

I am using Strawberry Perl on an Windows 7 box, and modified Google::Voice version 0.06

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Mojolicious version is too new. Mojo::DOM::attrs was removed since 4.50: [see Mojolicious Cahnges](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Mojolicious#L78). Now the method name is Mojo::DOM::attr.

You can decrease your Mojolicious version or just fill bug report for Google::Voice